# Allow user to resize window such that Gtk3 TextView component can't show all text

Tags: resize, gtk, gtk3, window-resize

I'm working on a GTK program in Rust (someone can probably answer this if they don't know Rust, as I can figure out how to translate between different bindings and the native C API) via the gtk-rs bindings for which I want to have a non-editable `TextView` who's contents are constantly updated in my code. I want the user to be able to resize the `TextView` to any size, after which my code will re-calculate its contents accordingly. Unfortunately, GTK prevents any resize from taking place that would hide any contents that are current in the `TextView`. I can't use a `ScrolledWindow` because I don't want visible scrollbars, and disabling the scrollbars on a `ScrolledWindow` prevents the resizing behavior that I want. I also tried calling `set_size_request` to set the size to both 1, 1, and 0, 0 after every text change, but this does not change the behavior at all either — the user still can't properly resize the `TextView` (by resizing the window).

How can I enable the resizing behavior that I want?

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is not possible. What would be the point of resizing the text view smaller, if the user can never see the text that is outside of the viewport because you don't want scrollbars? That seems like it would confound the user's expectation of how such a component would usually work.

Maybe an approach could be that you pick a certain number of lines to show, make that the size of the viewport, and delete the old contents of the text view that scroll outside of the viewport?